# Can't force HPZ600 workstation into PXE

Tags: hp, pxe-boot, hpc

I've got a HPC 2008 cluster of HP Z600 workstatsions, and though my head node can add them to the cluster (using node.xml files), and can reboot them, when the Z600 powers on the PXE attempt just times out.

When the cluster node boots up the head node reports that it is 'sending PXE command to boot node to WINPE (expected boot time: 5-15 minutes)'.

Meanwhile the cluster node goes into PXE, but sits twiddling it's timer before reporting a PXE-M0f then finally a non-system disk error.

HP UNDI PXE-2.1 V11.4.0 
HP Base Code PXE-2.1 v1.1.0

Any advice on forcing these Z600s to take their medicine gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a PXE-E52 error code reported - though only intermittently.

I've reconfigured the DHCP and now that the Z600 is picking up an IP address PXE is working.